# Validation not working on jquery.steps with more than one select2 select input

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-select2, jquery-steps

I have the following HTML code to create a jquery.step-like wizard which includes 3 select2 input controls:

```
<form id="form" action="#" >
       <h1>Data Package source information</h1>
       <fieldset>
            <h2>Specify the details of the new Data Package</h2>
            <div class="row">
                 <div class="col-lg-8" id="importFileData">
                      <div class="form-group">
                           <label>Customer *</label>
                           <select class="form-control required" id="selectCustomer" data-bind="options: customers, optionsText: 'Name', optionsValue: 'Id'"></select>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                           <label>System type *</label>
                           <select class="form-control required" id="selectSystem" data-bind="options: systems, optionsText: 'Name', optionsValue: 'TypeId'"></select>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Select the instrument where the data package comes from *</label>
                            <select class="form-control required" id="selectInstrument" data-bind="options: instruments, optionsText: 'SerialNumber', optionsValue: 'SerialNumber'"></select>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="font-noraml">Select the date of import (by default today)</label>
                            <div class="input-group date">
                                 <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span><input id="importDate" type="text" class="form-control" value="@DateTime.Now.ToString("d")">
                            </div>
                      </div>
                 </div>
                 <div class="col-lg-4">
                      <div class="text-center">
                            <div style="margin-top: 20px">
                                  <i class="fa fa-sign-in" style="font-size: 180px; color: #e5e5e5"></i>
                            </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
            </div>
      </fieldset>
</form>
```

And here the Javascript:

```
 $("#form")
            .steps({
                bodyTag: "fieldset",
                onStepChanging: function (event, currentIndex, newIndex) {
                    var form = $(this);
                    // Always allow going backward even if the current step contains invalid fields!
                    if (currentIndex > newIndex) {
                        return true;
                    }

                    form.validate();

                    // Start validation; Prevent going forward if false
                    return form.valid();
                },
                onStepChanged: function (event, currentIndex, priorIndex) {

                },
                onFinishing: function (event, currentIndex) {
                    var form = $(this);
                    form.validate();
                    // Start validation; Prevent form submission if false
                    return form.valid();
                },
                onFinished: function (event, currentIndex) {
                    var form = $(this);

                    // Submit form input
                    form.submit();
                }
            })
            .validate({
                errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
                    element.before(error);
                }
            });

        $("#selectCustomer")
            .select2({
                placeholder: "Select a customer",
                allowClear: true
            })
            .on("change",
                function (e) {
                    var selectedCustomerId = $("#selectCustomer").val();

                    $.ajax({
                        url: self.getValidUrl() + "/api/DataPackageManagementApi/Systems/" + selectedCustomerId,
                        async: true,
                        type: "GET",
                        success: function (results) {
                            self.importDataPackageViewModel.systems.removeAll();
                            self.importDataPackageViewModel.systems.push("");

                            $.each(results,
                                function (key, item) {
                                    self.importDataPackageViewModel.systems.push(item);
                                });

                            $("#selectSystem").prop("disabled", false);
                        },
                        error: function (jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                            console.log(JSON.stringify(jqXhr));
                            console.log("AJAX error: " + textStatus + " : " + errorThrown);
                        }
                    });
                });

        $("#selectSystem")
            .select2({
                placeholder: "Select a system",
                allowClear: true,
                disabled: true
            })
            .on("change",
                function (e) {
                    var selectedCustomerId = $("#selectCustomer").val();
                    var selectedSystemId = $("#selectSystem").val();
                    $.ajax({
                        url: self.getValidUrl() + "/api/DataPackageManagementApi/Instruments/" +selectedCustomerId +"/" +selectedSystemId,
                        async: true,
                        type: "GET",
                        success: function (results) {
                            self.importDataPackageViewModel.instruments.removeAll();
                            self.importDataPackageViewModel.instruments.push("");

                            $.each(results,
                                function (key, item) {
                                    self.importDataPackageViewModel.instruments.push(item);
                                });

                            $("#selectInstrument").prop("disabled", false);
                        },
                        error: function (jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                            console.log(JSON.stringify(jqXhr));
                            console.log("AJAX error: " + textStatus + " : " + errorThrown);
                        }
                    });
                });

        $("#selectInstrument")
            .select2({
                placeholder: "Select a Instrument",
                allowClear: true,
                disabled: true
            });
```

My problem are two:

1. The validation of the form only validates the first select2 input control, never the second nor the third.
2. The style of the select2 validation error does not match with the rest of the validation controls.

Does anyone know what am I doing wrong? I've searched both jquery.validation and select2 documentation and examples and to me it looks like I'm doing it correctly, but obviously there is a mistake somewhere.

Many thanks in advance!

Regards,

Javier

Answer (score 0):

You can validate something like this:

```
$('#form-add-comment').validate({
    onkeyup: false,
    rules: {
        Comment: "required"
    },
    messages: {
        Comment: "Please enter Comment"
    },
    errorClass: "has-error",
    validClass: "success",
    highlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
        var elem = $(element);
        if (elem.hasClass("select2-offscreen")) {
            elem.parent().addClass('Select2Error');
        }
        else {
            elem.parent().addClass(errorClass);
        }

    },
    unhighlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
        var elem = $(element);
        if (elem.parent().hasClass(errorClass))
            elem.siblings('.error-container').remove();
        if (elem.hasClass("select2-offscreen")) {
            $("#" + elem.attr("id")).on("change", function () {
                $(this).parent.removeClass("Select2Error");
            });
            elem.parent().removeClass('Select2Error');
            elem.siblings('.error-container').remove();
        }
        else {
            elem.parent().removeClass(errorClass);
        }
    },
    errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
        var container = $('<div />');
        container.addClass('error-container');
        $("#" + element[0].id).addClass('disp-error');
        error.insertBefore(element);
        error.wrap(container);
        error.insertBefore(error);
    },
});
```